# How do I get rid of the unwanted, ugly "?" mark icon/button polluting the File Explorer in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Located in the top-right corner of every File Explorer window, just underneath the "X" button, is an ugly eyesore of an icon displaying a question mark ("?"). If accidentally clicked -- which has happened to me about 37 trillion times since Windows 10 came out and I installed it -- it forcibly opens a browser and goes to a Bing search result, displaying the same meaningless, unwanted pages that all search engines display for just about any search query.

I hate that button. It looks ugly, it is deeply disrespectful and I never, ever want to make any search engine query as a result of trying to close a window.

Like about 100 other things in Windows 10, I have spent countless hours, days, weeks of my life searching and asking and trying anything I could think of to get rid of this. No luck whatsoever. I truly feel like the computer is in control of me -- not the other way around.

There must be a nice little .reg file to run to get this thing gone already. I refuse to believe that Windows veterans and all kinds of intelligent and experienced people actually just accept and deal with things like this.

PS: I have both Winaero Tweaker and Spybot Anti-Beacon installed, but both are very limited in what they can do.

Comment: I sorry, there's so much rant in here its hard to see your question. Though, from what I can tell, you're asking about the help button (if you are, why don't you just say so? Your "question" would be far better if you did), and no, it's kijda built in to the UI and not likely to be "tweaked" out of the interface.

Answer (score 3):

It is the help button and built into Explorer. So far as I know, you cannot remove it. I just ignore it myself.